# Intellij is not recognizing docker maven dependency

Tags: java, docker, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use maven to get the dependency below and intellij is saying that it's not found and I can't figure out why, there doesn't seem to be anything on google. The dependency is listed in the maven website [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.docker-java/docker-jav) so I know it exists. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.docker-java/docker-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have a user settings.xml file that might be proxying your requests to a custom repo?

Comment: @Deadron no I don't, it's basically a brand new project and I just added maven

Comment: Try forcing Intellij to run maven install -U to force re-resolution of dependencies. Sometimes the initial resolution fails and maven unhelpfully caches that resolution.

Comment: @Deadron I tried that, it didn't fix it

Comment: Is it just the editor showing it as unresolved in the pom.xml or does it fail to compile? Sometimes the pom file shows as not found but it did find it.  Try from the command line to eliminate a Intellij issue.

Comment: Does `mvn clean compile` run successfully in terminal for this project?

Comment: Is the problem only with this dependency? If you have proxies in network - make sure you have configured them with Maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html